# Can foreign military flying hours be counted towards an EASA ATPL in Hungary?

Tags: military, easa-regulations, pilot-certification, logging, indian-air-force

I'm an ex- Indian Air Force helicopter pilot with about 4000 hours of flying experience, including some 2500 hours as captain and about 500 hours as an instructor.

Is there any means by which, I can get the flying I have done in the Indian Military, at least partially counted towards the requirement for obtaining an EASA ATPL licence. I am currently enrolled in a flying school in Hungary and they insist I fly the same syllabus as an ab-initio, as according to their Compliance Manager, no part of my flying experience can be added towards the requirement of Hungarian CAA for grant of ATPL.

I have tried to contact Hungarian CAA, but haven't received a response yet.

Would be grateful for suggestions/tips!